# Syslog logging to syslog.1 not syslog

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, logrotate, log-rotation

My syslog file is getting a bit unmanageable. I believed I had configured this previously to rotate daily but obviously something has gone amiss.

At the moment, my /var/log looks like this:

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm             0 Feb 25 06:25 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm     696223089 Jul 15 12:06 syslog.1.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        518918 Feb 24 06:25 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        273006 Feb 23 06:25 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        309765 Feb 22 06:25 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        545437 Feb 21 06:25 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        545733 Feb 20 06:25 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        646461 Feb 19 06:25 syslog.7.gz
```

Syslog continues to log to *syslog.1.1* but not to *syslog*.

/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog looks like:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
            reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

And my syslog entry in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf looks like:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

Running

```
sudo logrotate --force rsyslog
```

Doesn't seem to move this along.

Comment: Did you make sure that `reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true` does work?

Comment: I ran this from the command line but no effect on the logs

Answer (score 2):

Put this line:

```
invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
```

instead of:

```
reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
```

It will cause rsyslog to properly reload, close rotated files and new open log files for writing.

Comment: I amended this and ran

   **sudo logrotate --force rsyslog**

But no joy. I ran

    **reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true**

And was told that...

    **The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but rotate is not supported for Upstart jobs.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "rotate" failed**

Comment: Ok, so execute "service rsyslog reload" instead.

Comment: Sorry. Should have said that I did try that. `service rsyslog reload` states `reload: Not running`. `service rsyslog status` states `rsyslog start/running`.

Comment: Try "service rsyslog restart", maybe reload doesn't work on Upstart...

Comment: Think I've found a reason for this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1331891. Seems "reload" is not supported by upstart jobs. An updated fix was provided for 14.04 but we're using 12.04 LTS so not sure how that can be installed on this. I thought that if we were using an LTS, these types of things would be fixed?